# SQL simple select statement with multiple rows

Tags: sql, select, syntax

Is there a way to write a select statement that will create multiple rows from a string literal select statement?

Select '123' as row1 will produce a table like:

```
row1 |

123
```

Select '123' as row1, '456' as row2 will produce

```
row1 |  row2|

123    456
```

My question is, what is the correct syntax to make multiple rows with the same field heading such as:

```
row1 |
 123
 456
 789
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `union all`.  In most databases;

```
select '123' as row1
union all
select '456' 
union all
select '789';
```

Some databases require a `from` clause.  For instance, Oracle wants `from dual` and DB2 wants `from sysibm.sysdummy1`.

Comment: Also ANSI SQL requires the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you with the results you are looking for:

```
[db2inst1@dbms ~]$ db2 "values('123'),('456'),('789')"

1  
---
123
456
789

  3 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: As with the original question: which database system would this apply to?